# Golang intermittent behaviour on timed out Goroutine

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine, channel

I am trying to implement concurrency for repetitive task. I want to implement an http request on a different Goroutine (pictured by `longRunningTask` function). I provide a timer for a mechanism to stop the Goroutine and sends a timeout signal to the main Goroutine if the heavy load task proceed the predefined timeout. The problem that I currently have is that I am getting intermittent behaviour.

The code has been simplified to look like below.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var iteration int = 5

    timeOutChan := make(chan struct{})
    resultChan := make(chan string)

    for i := 0; i < iteration; i++ {
        go longRunningTaks(timeOutChan, resultChan)
    }

    for i := 0; i < iteration; i++ {
        select {
        case data := <-resultChan:
            fmt.Println(data)
        case <-timeOutChan:
            fmt.Println("timed out")
        }
    }

}

func longRunningTaks(tc chan struct{}, rc chan string) {
    timer := time.NewTimer(time.Nanosecond * 1)
    defer timer.Stop()

    // Heavy load task
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)

    select {
    case <-timer.C:
        tc <- struct{}{}
    case rc <- "success":
        return
    }
}
```

I believe every tries should be printing out

```
timeout
timeout
timeout
timeout
timeout
```

Instead I got an intermittent

```
success
timeout
timeout
timeout
timeout
```

Comment: ["If one or more of the communications can proceed, a single one that can proceed is chosen via a uniform pseudo-random selection."](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements) The send on rc can verly likely proceed since there is a matching receive in main. Your program simply isn't deterministic.

Comment: @Peter I dont quite understand, how could rc proceed while the sleep is longer than the timeout? Also, what do you mean by it is not simply deterministic?

Comment: @Adam Your "timeout" doesn't time anything out. You *always* wait for the sleep to complete and then check if some time ago a "timeout" occurred; you do that check in the same step that sees if a result can be sent. Both will be possible and the choice of which to do is complete arbitrary.  This isn't how you do timeouts in Go.

Answer (score -1):

The doc mentions:

> NewTimer creates a new Timer that will send the current time on its
>   channel after **at least duration d**.

"at least means" timer will take specified time for sure, however this also implicitly means can take more time than specified. Timer starts its own go routine and write to channel on expiry.
Because of scheduler or garbage collection or processes of writing to other channel can get delayed. Besides simulated work load is very short considering above possibilities.

**Update**:

As Peter mentioned in comment writing "success" to rc channel is action which is equally likely to complete because that can be read from the other end by main routine. The select has to choose between 1) writing "success" to rc channel & 2) expired timer. And both are possible.
The likelihood of No1 is more in the beginning because the main routine is yet to read it from other end. Once that happens. Other remaining routines will have to **compete** for the channel (to write "success") (since it is blocking with buffer size 0) so for rest of the times the likelihood of expired timer getting selected is more as cannot say how fast the main routine will read from the resultChan channel (other end of rc).

Comment: If it is actually the reason, I don't think that it would take more time than the sleep.

Comment: As Peter mentioned `rc <- "success"` is something which also is also equally qualified event for the `select ` against the expired timer. I did not realize that. `select` call on 1) expired timer OR 2) writing "success" to a channel that can be read from the other end, are 2 equally competing event.